# Define and use functions inside macros

Tags: macros, elixir

Following this example:

```
defmodule Greetify do

  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      Module.register_attribute __MODULE__, :greet, accumulate: true,
        persist: false
      @before_compile Greetify
    end
  end

  defmacro __before_compile__(env) do
    greetings = Module.get_attribute(env.module, :greet)
    for {name, age} <- greetings do
      IO.puts "#{name} is #{age} years old"
    end
  end

end
```

Can it be possible to define internal functions to use within the macro?

For example:

```
  defmacro __before_compile__(env) do
    greetings = Module.get_attribute(env.module, :greet)
    say_greetings(greetings)

    defp say_greetings(grettings) do
      for {name, age} <- greetings do
        IO.puts "#{name} is #{age} years old"
      end
    end
  end
```

Trying this the compiler complais with function say_grettings is not defined

That example source http://elixir-recipes.github.io/metaprogramming/accumulating-annotations/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is possible. The issue with your code is that you mix the scopes. Macros in Elixir are being expanded during the compilation stage. There is no compiled `say_greetings/1` function at this very moment (besides that one cannot invoke `defp` from inside `defmacro`, but this might be overcame with a proper quoting.)

What you need for this to work, would be to declare `say_greetings/1` in the same scope as `__before_compile__/1` to make is available for it. You cannot define it as a function (see above,) but the workaround would be to define it *as a macro as well*. That way it will be *expanded* during a compilation and everything will work (also, I doubt I understand what is the reason for that.)

The summing up:

```rb
defmodule Greetify do    
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      Module.register_attribute __MODULE__, :greet, accumulate: true, persist: false
      @before_compile Greetify
    end
  end

  defmacrop say_greetings(greetings) do
    quote do
      for {name, age} <- unquote(greetings) do
        IO.puts "#{name} is #{age} years old"
      end
    end
  end

  defmacro __before_compile__(env) do
    greetings = Module.get_attribute(env.module, :greet)
    say_greetings(greetings)
  end
end

defmodule Test do
  use Greetify

  @greet {"Jon", 21}
  @greet {"Sam", 23}
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes I knew they are compiled that's why I though it could work with before_compile macro. So, for example, if I had to use several functions not just "say_greetings", all of them must be a separated macro right? to be avaible within before_compile scope

Comment: Macros _are not compiled_, they are expanded into AST inplace _before compilation_, that’s why they are accessible _before compilation starts_. Honestly, I can not invent the other solution save for putting them into separate macro, but I am not sure it’s impossible to accomplish in other way,

Comment: mm but could invoke def inside macro with proper quoting as you said?

Comment: Yes, but one cannot make it possible to execute a function that is not yet compiled. You can declare it, yes, but not call.